# RMI tranfer file

Tags: java, io

I have been given a task where I have been asked to implement a Java RMI, Client / Server. It must use the following commands:

list - list files in current directory
download - copy file from server to client
upload - upload file from client to server

I have read many tutorials but I do not get any clear guideline to do that.
any help would be appreciated

Thanks

this is the tutorial that i am using http://www.censhare.com/en/insight/overview/article/file-streaming-using-java-rmi

Answer (score 0):

you can upload file on ftp server using  **apache commons**  please try this code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.SocketException;

    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

    public class Ftpdemo {  


         public static void main(String args[]) {  

          // get an ftpClient object  
          FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();  
          ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(300);
          FileInputStream inputStream = null;  

          try {  
           // pass directory path on server to connect  
           ftpClient.connect("ftp.mydomain.in");  

           // pass username and password, returned true if authentication is  
           // successful  
           boolean login = ftpClient.login("myusername", "mypassword");  

           if (login) {  
            System.out.println("Connection established...");  
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            inputStream = new FileInputStream("image/path/mypic.png");  

            boolean uploaded = ftpClient.storeFile("user_screens/test3.png",inputStream);



                  if (uploaded) {  
             System.out.println("File uploaded successfully !");  
            } else {  
             System.out.println("Error in uploading file !");  
            }  

            // logout the user, returned true if logout successfully  
            boolean logout = ftpClient.logout();  
            if (logout) {  
             System.out.println("Connection close...");  
            }  
           } else {  
            System.out.println("Connection fail...");  
           }  

          } catch (SocketException e) {  
           e.printStackTrace();  
          } catch (IOException e) {  
           e.printStackTrace();  
          } finally {  
           try {  
            ftpClient.disconnect();  
           } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
           }  
          }  
         }


        }
```

Comment: I  just want to upload file from client to server and download file from server to client using RMI in my computer, so i need to create connection using registry and then perform the tasks.

Comment: you mention FTP so i think you need ftp to connect with java code

Comment: sorry, i removed FTP, i did the same question in java using socket but i do not have idea in how to do it using RMI.

Comment: why you need RMI there is lots of there ways using Web-services for example.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1183133?start=0&tstart=0 please see this discussion it may help you

Comment: actually the  supervisor asked me to do that and i do not have choice to change, that why i want to use RMI.

Comment: above discussion will help you.